# Google Sheets Function replication

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, range, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to have a function that contains two ranges and you want to drag that formula across multiple cells but only have one of the ranges auto-advance while keeping the other function the original without advancing?

Here is the function

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!A5:A31, Input!JZ5:JZ="V")))
```

I want to drag this across multiple cells in a row, however, I only want the Input!JZ5:JZ="V" portion to advance to Input!KA5:KA="V"  and leave the Input!A5:A31 the same due to that's the location of the information I am looking for and doesn't change.

Currently, both will advance to the next cell and so I am having to go back and fix each one and I have about 300 of these I need to do.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, lock it down with `$` symbols. try:

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$31, Input!JZ5:JZ="V")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew there was a way, Sometimes when your looking at the forest you forget to pay attention to the trees. LOL Thanks again